# What does the number mean in the output of strace?

Tags: strace

```
6331  execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
6331  brk(0)                            = 0x601000
```

What does `6331` mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `6331` in your example is the process id; it comes in handy when you `strace(1)` with the `-f` or `-F` flags a program that spawns other programs. For a quick example, try this:

```
strace -o /tmp/out -fF /etc/init.d/cron status
```

(There's nothing magical about that initscript, I just figured it'd be a script that you have on your system.)

The `/tmp/out` file will show you the output from several processes, and each will be prefixed with its pid:

```
22631 read(10, "#!/bin/sh -e\n# upstart-job\n#\n# S"..., 8192) = 1826
22631 pipe([3, 4])                      = 0
22631 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fcb01efd9d0) = 22632
22631 close(4)                          = 0
22632 close(10 <unfinished ...>
22631 read(3,  <unfinished ...>
22632 <... close resumed> )             = 0
22632 close(3)                          = 0
22632 dup2(4, 1)                        = 1
22632 close(4)                          = 0
22632 stat("/home/sarnold/bin/basename", 0x7fffb751ce30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

You can see the creation of the new process with the `clone(2)` call (which is how Linux has implemented `fork()`, in newer versions of the kernel).

Comment: What do the numbers mean in strace(1) and clone(2) ?

Comment: @compiler, the `(1)` and `(2)` show manpage sections. `(1)` is a user-level command (`ls(1)`, `printf(1)`), `(2)` is a kernel-provided system call (`fork(2)`, `getpid(2)`, `(3)` is a library-provided function (`printf(3)`, `signal(3)`), `(4)` is device driver (`/dev/null` is in `null(4)`, `mga(4)`), `(5)` is configuration files (`smb.conf(5)`, `ssh_config(5)`), `(6)` is games (`robots(6)`, `wump(6)`), `(7)` is for high-level overviews (`ip(7)`, `udp(7)`, `signal(7)`), and `(8)` is sysadmin commands (`shutdown(8)`, `reboot(8)`, `ifconfig(8)`). Try `man 1 printf` and `man 3 printf`.

Comment: What's the default section when we just `man xxx` without a number ?

Comment: @compiler, good question! :) `printf`, `sync`, `random`, and `futex` all seem to pick the lowest-numbered page, but `man umount` returns `umount(8)` rather than `umount(2)`. It feels like it looks in this order: 1 8 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Wow, I learned more about the man pages right here than I ever have anywhere else.